# Android Google Maps V2 User Location

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, geolocation

The blue dot/arrow isnt showing on my map. Everything else works fine. Am i missing some permissions?

Included the Java Class, Manifest and layout XML.

```
private void setUpMap(int satelliteMode, LatLng startPoint, float zoomLevel) {

        mapView.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        //mapView.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        mapView.setMapType(satelliteMode);
        mapView.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mapView.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(startPoint, zoomLevel));
    }
```

xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

manifest:

```
<permission
         android:name="com.example.project.MAPS_RECEIVE"
         android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission  android:name="com.example.project.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >

        <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
           android:value="API_KEY"/>
```

Comment: Does it work with the Google Maps app on this device? There's an issue in newer versions of Android where you have to give permission to Google Maps specifically via the Accounts area of the Settings app for it to be able to use GPS. It is conceivable that this also affects the V2 Maps stuff.

Comment: sadly the blue dot shows up fine in the google maps application on my samsung galaxy s2

Comment: The in-device settings of my app even say that this app can access "Your location" (also has "Network communication")

Comment: I would just like to point out that i am currently having the same exakt issue with almost identical code :/

Comment: so nobody has a solution for this? Hope android fixes this soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it just worked. Went away for lunch and left the app on. When i returned the blue arrow was drawn on the map. Not on the right location though but it was on the map. So the posted code of mine works. It only needs an update from the location manager.

Comment: When I run tour code it gives me error that  **java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView**
I useGoogle Inc.:Google APIs:10 and MAP V2 too.

Answer (score 3):

You'd see that clicking the 'my location' button creates the blue dot at your current location. Using the location manager to track location updates and moving the camera accordingly allows you to track the user too, without clicking the button. See a snippet below.

```
LocationListener ll = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Moved to "+arg0.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            CameraPosition cp = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(),arg0.getLongitude()))
            .zoom(12)
            .build();     
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cp));
        }
}
```

Comment: Where do you register this listener? Is it on the `LocationManager` system service instead of the `Map`?

Comment: clicking the my location button doesnt even creates the blue dot in my case.

Comment: Yes, the LocationManager, as in: LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, time, distance, LocationListener);

Comment: @MarkMolina How are you initializing mapView? I use:
    GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

Comment: exactly the same:

public void setUpMapIfNeeded(int satelliteMode, LatLng startPoint, float zoomLevel) {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mapView == null) {
            
         mapView = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mapView != null) {
                setUpMap(satelliteMode, startPoint, zoomLevel);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: mapView = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview))
                    .getMap();

Comment: @MarkMolina try creating a button that centers the map on your current location. This is just to test if the mapView is actually receiving location information. Consider using the emulator or another device too.

Comment: Regarding your last line, moveCamera(), You should be aware that while setMyLocationEnabled() should draw the blue marker, it doesn't actually try to keep the marker in the visible bounds.

Comment: doensnt the standard location button zooms to the current location? Its enabled by default but just to make sure:
mapView.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, i have the exact same problem as the original post on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.
However, i do NOT have the issue on an Archos 101G9.

If I reboot, load my app with Google Maps v2 and click the 'go to my location' button in the top right, the Archos goes directly to my current location but the SGT2 does nothing.

If I manually get my current location using location manager and animate the map to it then it navigates. However clicking the 'go to my location' button still does nothing.

Getting a location fix using GPS seems to fix the issue.

EDIT:
On the SGT2 the blue location dot appears only with a GPS fix, however the Archos displays the blue dot with a mobile data/wifi fix.

Answer (score 0):

Hi in you FragmentActivity add implements LocationListener

```
private LocationManager locationManager;
```

In `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.... add

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

Criteria locationCriteria = new Criteria();
locationCriteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);       locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.getBestProvider(locationCriteria, true), 1L, 2F, this);
```

and implemented methos to LocationListener ;)